# Как работает перебор свойств объекта?

Tags: javascript

```js
var o = {0:'Guest', 1:0, 2:false}; 
for (var cur = 0; cur in o; cur++) { 
  console.log(cur + ": " + o[cur]); 
}
```

Не могу понять как работает этот код? Мы в цикле for создаём переменную cur и в условии проверяем ее наличие в объекте o. Но ее там нет, условие должно выдать false и цикл не выполнится.

Comment: просто это массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. var cur = 0; - инициализируем переменную cur со значением 0.
2. cur in o; - проверяем, есть ли в объекте свойство со значением, которое лежит в этой переменной. На первой итерации это 0, так что можно интерпретировать это как "0 in o". А в объекте есть такое свойство (0:'Guest');
3. Потом в переменной увеличиваем значение переменной до 1, потом до 2, пока оно не достигнет 3.

Скорее всего, недопонимание было в том, что вы ожидали от оператора "in", что в случае "cur in o" он вернет true, если в объекте будет свойство {cur: 'Guest'}. Чтобы добиться такого эффекта, нужно передать оператору не переменную, а строку: "'cur' in o".